# CSS - text-shadow size

Tags: css

I am trying to get this effect:
[image]
As you see, shadow is bigger then text. How can I set size of shadow against to text (like shadow size is 150% of text size)?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think text shadow could work like this. Could we use before pseudo element make it blur and giving it font size. position would be absolute. What do you think. Suggestions would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I far as know, You can't set the text-shadow size.

If you want to set size, you must use a trick like this.

```css
p{
  font-size: 60pt;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

span{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 90pt;
  filter: blur(10px);
  top: 5px;
  left: 0px;

}
```

```html
<p>TEXT<span>TEXT</span></p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if op just support only some browser, else cross browser this will get some problem in IE (filter does not support in IE) :P

Comment: @Mr Lister      Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 7):

or use multiple light sources for text-shadow, so it appears bigger than original.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  text-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75),
              -3px 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<h1>
    Text
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

The text-shadow has the same size as the text itself, so you will need to use two elements, one containing the size and one containing the shadow.

```css
div.main {
  font-size:6rem;
  position:relative;
}
div.main .shadow {
  position:absolute;
  color:transparent;
  font-size:120%;
  left:0; top:0;
  text-shadow:-.1em .15em .15em black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  Text
  <div class="shadow">Text</div>
</div>
```

Since this would involve writing the content twice (once in each element), which may not always be convenient, we can use a little trick to avoid this: put the text in an attribute and use its value for displaying. That way, we can also do away with the inner element.

```css
div[data-shadow] {
  font-size:6rem;
  position:relative;
}
div[data-shadow]::before {
  content:attr(data-shadow);
}
div[data-shadow]::after {
  position:absolute;
  content:attr(data-shadow);
  color:transparent;
  font-size:120%;
  left:0; top:0;
  text-shadow:-.1em .15em .15em black;
}
```

```html
<div data-shadow="Test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**, the image you shared obviously is not made with CSS. Why?

1. CSS text-shadow can't have its own font-size
2. In the image you shared, the 'T' shadow is just below it, but 'x' shadow is below and in far right!

My solution to what you want is as in this JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/AbdullahAlemadi/0cu0eyq2/

To have what you want:

- I made the shadow as another text element
- The Shadowed text has transparent color and bigger font size
- Then I played with text-shadow.

HTML

```
<h2 class="shadow">Headline</h2>
<h2>Headline</h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
h2.shadow {
  top: 15px;
  left: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use multiple objects
this is what u need to do exactly to complete your task :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    text-shadow: 0 18px 20px #585858, 0 18px 20px #585858, 0 20px 20px #585858,0 20px 20px #585858, 0 20px 20px #585858;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="font-size:100px;">Text</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example that shows how this solves the OP's problem?

Comment: It doesn't make the text shadow bigger. It just intensifies it.

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```css
div{
 text-shadow: 15px 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>TEXT</div>
```

Comment: How does this address the OP's problem?

Comment: The idea was making text-shadow bigger, not the text itself.