# CSS - Shadow behind letter

Tags: css, css-transforms, shadow

I want to make a text effect with shadow behind letter, like this:
[image]
This is my code:

```css
span {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 110pt;
  text-shadow: -14pt 18pt 4pt rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<span>Text</span>
```

but this it simple text shadow, I need to transform it. How can I create this effect using CSS and **only one** HTML tag like `<span>`?
Thanks for help.

Comment: https://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/yGpAK  try this

Comment: Fine, but it not solve my problem

Comment: The solution to this is basically the same as to [your other question about a text-shadow with different metrics than the text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45607356/1016716)...

Comment: Try this link: https://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/yGpAK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a psuedo element instead of a shadow:

```css
[data-shadowtext] {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 150px;
}

[data-shadowtext]::before,
[data-shadowtext]::after {
  content: attr(data-shadowtext);
}

[data-shadowtext]::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -60px;
  left: 3px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  /* the text is 20% larger than the parent */
  color: transparent;
  /* hide the text */
  text-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
  /* create a shadow only from the blur */
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: rotateX(75deg) skew(15deg);
  letter-spacing: -15px;
}

[data-shadowtext]::after {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  margin: 20px 0 0 80px;
}
```

```html
<div data-shadowtext="Text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with writing core CSS.
You can only use as generated by Text Shadow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same but you can get the idea !!

```css
span {
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      position: relative;
      padding: 20px;
      border: none;
      font: normal 100px/1 "Oswald", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #e74c3c;
      text-align: center;
      -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      letter-spacing: 15px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
    }
    
    span:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
      content: "Text";
      top: 34px;
      left: 28px;
      padding: 20px;
      border: none;
      font: normal 77px/1 "Oswald", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      text-align: center;
      -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      letter-spacing: 23px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(50deg)   skewX(-30deg);
      transform: rotateX(50deg)   skewX(-30deg);
    }
```

```html
<span title="Text">Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate method and its matrix property.:

My JS Fiddle Example : https://jsfiddle.net/gsmjjm7b/

HTML:

```
<div id="relative">

  <h1 id="title">TEXT</h1>
  <h1 class="shadow">TEXT</h1>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#relative{position:relative;margin:100px}

h1 {font-size:80px;margin:0}

h1.shadow {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-25px;
  -ms-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.7, 1, 0, 0); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.7, 1, 0, 0); /* Safari */
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.7, 1, 0, 0);
  text-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:1;color:rgba(0,0,0,0)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of displaying,

```css
span {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 110pt;
}

span:before {
  bottom: 2px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  content: attr(title);
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px grey;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: skew(30deg) scale(0.8, 1);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span title="Text">Text</span>
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful too. Thanks.